# Mouse clickAndHold() not working properly on Firefox Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver client 2.39 and Firefox 26.

Mouse click and hold event does not work properly. My code is like

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com/2013/12/frmset1.html");
WebElement multiSelectDropDown=driver.findElement(By.name("multiselectdropdown"));
List<WebElement> dropdownlists = multiSelectDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(0)).
               clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(6)).click().build();
```

This code does not give any error but select only one element.
I can bypass this issue using other way but I want to know whay it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the same problem but it select the element from start to last and give some Error like

Cannot perform native interaction: Could not get node for element - cannot interact

I got the solution by this way you can do this for your problem

```
 builder.clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(0)).moveToElement(dropdownlists.get(6)).release().build().perform();
```

Comment: yeap I do the same thing to escape this problem,by the way thanks for your help

Comment: moin and saba, are you guys playing amongst yourselves. The same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806671/selenium-webdriver-clickandhold-error-on-firefox was asked by saba and moin answered it and in this question reverse. moin asked question and saba answered. What is the intention behind asking same question and answering each other's question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple option from your list try this (it will select first 3 elements):

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='multiselectdropdown']/option"));
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(elements.get(i)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
    }
```

Comment: @ Andrian thanks for your help.I have 2 things 
1.I want to select element not sequentially means randomly click on element
2.Here you use keyboard event I want to use only mouse event.
3.I did not find any bypass solution I want to know why it was not working.Is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

ButtonUp (or `release()`) should be the next button-action following a ButtonDown (or `clickAndHold()`) button-action (see Appium [notes](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/mouse/button-down/) for ButtonDown documentation). Your code performs two consecutive `clickAndHolds()` followed by a `click()` without performing a `release()`. It should be something like:

```
   WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com/2013/12/frmset1.html");
   WebElement multiSelectDropDown=driver.findElement(By.name("multiselectdropdown"));
   List<WebElement> dropdownlists = multiSelectDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
   Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
   builder.clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(0)).moveTo(dropdownlists.get(6)).release().build();
```

While the linked documentation is not for Selenium, Appium is built on top of Selenium.