# Selenium Webdriver clickAndHold() error on Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to select multiple options from list but it does not select particular option it select from first choose options to last choose option and give some error like:

**Cannot perform native interaction: Could not get node for element - cannot interact**

My code is looks like

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();    
driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/selectable/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0));
WebElement multiSelectDropDown=driver.findElement(By.className("ui-selectable"));
List<WebElement> dropdownlists = multiSelectDropDown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(0)).
                   clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(4)).click()
                   .build().perform();
```

Can any one tell me why this is not working is there any problem in my code.

Comment: moin and saba, are you guys playing amongst yourselves. The same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801833/mouse-clickandhold-not-working-properly-on-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver was asked by moin and saba answered it and in this question reverse. saba asked question and moin answered. What is the intention behind asking same question and answering each other's question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this

```
  builder.clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(0)).
               clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(4)).click()
               .build().perform();
```

This should be looks like

```
  builder.clickAndHold(dropdownlists.get(0)).moveToElement(dropdownlists.get(4)).
               release().build().perform();
```

because in real world click the mouse and drag to the other element so moveto another element and then release the mouse.